# Ember - Issue with class binding within helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-validations

We upgraded to Ember 1.11.1 and Ember-validations 2.0.0-alpha.3.

**Controller**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend(EmberValidations.Mixin, { 
  canValidate: true,
  validationModel: Ember.computed.alias("model"),
  validations: {
   'validationModel.name': {
      presence: { 'if': 'canValidate', message: 'Please enter a name'},
   },
  },
}
```

**Template**

```
{{log "error value" errors.validationModel.name}}
{{input classBinding="errors.validationModel.name:app_input_box_error:app_input_box" placeholder="Document Name" value=model.name}}
```

With the above template code in place, validations works as expected and the input's class is swopped out depending on whether there is a validation error or not. However, when the {{log}} line is removed, the class binding seems to be lost and the input class is no longer appropriately updated. Any advice on the cause/fix please?

**Note** Class bindings outside helpers e.g. in a standard div continues to work properly

Comment: Works on my side with ember-validations: 2.0.0-alpha.3 and ember: 1.11.1!
Just created a new ember app and pasted your template/controller and created a simple route returning { name: 'test' }. -> Maybe you can post a jsbin?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
{{input classBinding="errors.validationModel.name:app_input_box_error:app_input_box" placeholder="Document Name" value=validationModel.name}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the issue is not with the binding of the value. It is with the binding of the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing `classBinding` but `classNameBindings` in the docs, I'm not sure if something was deprecated along the way.

I would suspect that the `classBinding` is not triggering the property to be updated, I seem to recall some issues with this on ember-validations at one point not always triggering. Have a look at https://github.com/aceofspades/ember-validations/commit/85ecaa348f2a1ccfb52f614037c4b4dbf77bceb4 and see if that might help.

From a higher level, I would think you'd be repeating this pattern often, adding a class name based on errors ties to the specific field. Personally I might spend some time looking for or building an input component that handles the annotation for ember-validations, where you can have a `fieldName` property and have it look at the appropriate `errors.validation.${fieldName}`. Coding in JS might help or at least make it easier to debug.

[This](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/rendering-errors-with-ember-validations/7663) is not precisely related to individual fields but might also be of help to you, in particular moving to HTMLBars syntax, i.e.

```
{{input class="{{if errors.validationModel.name 'app_input_box_error' 'app_input_box'}}"}}
```